# how to send null to an integer field - JAVA REST

Tags: java, mysql, json, rest

```
preparedStatement1.setInt(1,jsonObject1.getInteger("userid"));
```

database is mySQL. My userID field in the database is int type and is an optional field.

How can I easily pass NULL into this from json?

`{"userid":null}` is getting me error.

Comment: [`preparedStatement.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) ?

Comment: it is an optional field. It is possible that value may come in . So it should work even if the value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set an int field to null is with [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) rather than [`setInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)). `setInt` takes an `int` argument, so it cannot receive null as a value.

In your case you can use this to cover the case where the field may or may not be null:

```
Integer userId = jsonObject1.getInteger("userid");
if (userId==null) {
    preparedStatement1.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
} else {
    preparedStatement1.setInt(1, userId);
}
```

If you wanted you could write a helper method to do this more conveniently.

```
public static void setInteger(PreparedStatement stmt, int index, Integer value) {
    if (value==null) {
        stmt.setNull(index, Types.INTEGER);
    } else {
        stmt.setInt(index, value);
    }
}
```

then in context your operation is back to one line:

```
setInteger(preparedStatement1, 1, jsonObject1.getInteger("userid"));
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is the only way to do that. Was trying to see if it is possible in a single line.

Comment: It's easy to write a helper method that takes an `Integer` argument and null-checks it as above. It is a bit of an awkward design that Java sql uses basic types when it could use nullable object.